# Need help getting a list of people that like my photo on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

;/

Anyone here know how to record a list of people that like a photo in facebook? for example i have 1K ppl who like a single photo and i want to extract their name and facebook Id and put it into an excel sheet. Help! thanks!

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=473901719389878&set=a.473900502723333.1073741826.299200893526629&type=3&theater

here is the link of a photo anyone can help me in retreiving the list of names and fb id that liked the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=473901719389878%2Flikes)

```
473901719389878/likes
```

This will get a `josn` data with array containing `id` and `name` of people who liked that object

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "name": "Name X"
    },
    {
      "id": "YYYYYYYYY",
      "name": "Name Y"
    },
    {
      "id": "ZZZZZZZZZ",
      "name": "Name Z"
    }
         ]
   // More arrays here ...
}
```

Comment: I tried but it prompts with with an error ;/ saying
error request failed

Comment: How come? Did you click on the link in the answer body {UP}

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9Alv14Y.png

yea i did above is the error message i faced ;/

Comment: try this http://graph.facebook.com/473901719389878/likes?limit=1300